# Building a fat JAR for Spring application without Maven or Gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot

I built a Spring application using Eclipse. Due to various reasons, I was not able to set the project up as a Maven or Gradle project, but rather with the external JAR files explicitly downloaded and added.

Currently I can run the application, Spring starts up normally and behaves fully as expected. The problem occurs however as soon as I want to package the project.

As there is no other option, I have to use Eclipse's packaging tools. This is what I do:
`Export` -> `Java` -> `Runnable JAR file`

Then I check the option `Extract required libraries into generated JAR`.

When executed the resulting JAR file always throws this error:

```
ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories.
If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.
```

This spring.factories file looks like this:

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInfoFactory=org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfoFactory
```

I am aware of the solutions to this problem involving the use of Maven or Gradle. But these can not be applied here.

How could I get the fat JAR to run without Maven or Gradle?

Comment: Fair enough. Personally I'm not a fan of working within the bounds of arbitrary constraints. If I were working within an environment where using industry standard build tools was expressly prohibited, I would probably get myself out of that environment pretty fast. You obviously aren't so concerned by it.

Comment: Correct. It's a challenge, not a reason to quit.